# PHP: Abstract method within an interface

Tags: php, oop, interface, abstract, concrete

why cannot I declare an abstract method within an interface? This is my code. Thank you.

```
<?php
interface Connection {
    public abstract function connect();
    public function getConnection();
}

abstract class ConnectionAbstract implements Connection() {
    private $connection;

    public abstract function connect();

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}

class MySQLConnection extends ConnectionAbstract {
    public function connect() {
        echo 'connecting ...';
    }
}

$c = new MySQLConnection();
?>
```

Comment: At a guess I'd say because all methods within an interface are abstract, that's what interfaces are, collections of abstract methods.

Answer (score 17):

All functions in an interface are implicitly abstract. There is no need to use the abstract keyword when declaring the function.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that the requirement of a class which implements an interface must contain a series of public methods which correspond to the method signatures declared in the interface. So, for instance, when you declare an interface which has a defined `public abstract function`, you're literally saying that every class which implements the interface must have a public abstract method named `connect`. Since objects with abstract methods cannot be instantiated, you'll end up writing an interface which can never be used.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Although, aside from abstract methods allowing to have visibility other than public, are there any differences between a public abstract method and a public method in an interface?

Answer (score 1):

Both the methods in the Connection interface are abstract. All methods in an interface are implicitly abstract. So abstract keyword is not required for the connect() method.

Comment: How is this different from the first answer?